# Redirect camera to current position Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm trying to move camera to my current location, the thing that I've tried is :

My onCreateView looks like :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO handle this situation
        }

        mMapView = (MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(mBundle);


        setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);

        return inflatedView;
    }
```

My onCreate looks like :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBundle = savedInstanceState;
}
```

And I've got a method called setUpMapIfNeeded that inflates the view... The thing that i've tried is create a Location with my `mMap.getMyLocation()`, and then create two doubles `lat` and `lng` that they are = `location.getLatitude and Longitude`, and I tried to create a cameraZoomIn with my location but it doesn't works.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Location location = mMap.getMyLocation();
        double lat =  location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(location, 10);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

setUpMap method

```
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("PewPew"));
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

// create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Pew Pew");

// Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

// adding marker
        mMap.addMarker(marker);

    }
```

Hope you can help you solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to print your lat and lng and check that they have right values assigned? Also I am not sure what does the method setUpMap(); do...?

Comment: @Berťák In this method I'm creating the Marker etc...
On my map appears a blue circle where I am actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoogleMap.getLocation is deprecated, you should use the location service:

```
LocationManager mng = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = mng.getLastKnownLocation(mng.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false));

double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lon = location.getLongitude();

CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lon), 10);
mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: @JoanColmenero try: `getActivity().getSystemService()` if your code is in a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'm zooming

```
LatLng a = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(a, 10));
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: What is gps.getLatitude? Can you exmplain a bit your code?

Comment: ahh, sorry, gps is my own class and it's like location.getLatitude(); but I see that you already handled this problem.